# I can't refresh a div in my web

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

I'm trying to refresh a part of my web, a div, I found code about this, but It doesn't works. It seems it's correct but doesn't works. I don't understand what happens, I tried other jQuery codes and doesn't work too.

This is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timer;
        var seconds = 1; 

        $( document ).ready(function(){
           startActivityRefresh()
        });

        function startActivityRefresh() {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                $('#div1').load('prova.php');
            }, seconds*1000)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this the php file:

```
<?php
    echo "prova";
?>
```

When I go to the browser and reload the page doesn't show anything. It should show `prova`. (the php file is only a test)

**[RESOLVED]**
The problem where in my browser, firefox blocked the content. There was a shield in the url bar to unblock it.

Comment: For a start, you never call `startActivityRefresh`.

Comment: I call it and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Check your console, does it show any errors? Is prova.php actually where you've told it?

Comment: I tried this code http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load and with a .txt file works but not with a .php file. I tried to put a .txt file in my code and doesn't work, then this is not the problem :(

Comment: Finish I resolve it! The problem where in my browser, firefox blocked the content. There was a shield url bar to unblock it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! The problem where in my browser, firefox blocked the content. There was a shield in the url bar to unblock it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you never actually called `startActivityRefresh()`

Try this.

```
<script>
    var timer;
    var seconds = 1; 

    $( document ).ready(function(){
        startActivityRefresh()
    });

    function startActivityRefresh() {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $('#div1').load('prova.php');
        }, seconds*1000)
    }
</script>
```

Until it is called, the function is just hanging out, waiting for some other piece of code to need it.

I should also mention that there are at least two ways to call a function on page load. `$(document).ready` and `$(window).onload`. Here's a [discussion](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-and-window-onload-difference) on the difference.

EDIT:

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0gq3fn9/3/) that demonstrates the basic idea.

Comment: You should mark this answer as "Community Wiki" [Why?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269913/comment-poaching)

Comment: I tried your solution and doesn't work. It doesn't show anything. Is it possible that are a problem in my mac?

Comment: The script does work. I added a fiddle to demonstrate. Maybe `prova.php` isn't where you think it is? The [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) are very helpful in debugging javascript.

Comment: Finish I resolve it! The problem where in my browser, firefox blocked the content. There was a shield url bar to unblock it. Thanks anyway :)